# Asymptotic Behavior of Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving, mathematical-physics

physicist here.

I'm studying some problems that involve the use of differential equations. The professor of the course has indicated that usually variable changes used to simplify the equations come from an asymptotic analysis: 
For example if I try to analize then a equation like $\frac{dx}{dt}+x=\frac{t}{x}$, I would start making  $x \rightarrow 0$, and then solving the equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{t}{x}$. After that, I'll take dominant term $u(t)$ in the solution to make a variable change $x(t)=u(t)f(t)$ and then simplify (and solve) the equation.

The problem that now I'm facing is the following differential equation, at  $ x \rightarrow 1$:

$$ x^2 s \frac{d^2u(x)}{dx^2} + xs\frac{du(x)}{dx}+\frac{u(x)x}{c} \left ( \frac{p}{1-x} + \frac{q}{(1-x)^2}\right )=-K u(x)$$

My try: First I tried to change all that $x$ by 1 except the denominators, then solving the differential equation. It was completely impossible anyway. I've thought on power series, but that $1-x$ are very annoying. 
I've finally tried with Mathematica. I discovered that substituting the $x$ by 1 is NOT a good idea. Also now I'm pretty sure that the solution is an hypergeometric. However I could not solve the entire equation, I had to eliminate the $p/(1-x)$ term (the computer could not simplify in that case).

I need a good way to attack this. Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend multiplying the entire equation by $(1-x)^2$. This makes it clear that $u(x)xq/c$ is the leading term, since all others terms go with $(1-x)$ or  $(1-x)^2$. Now examine your equation. You must identify a term that may somehow balance the leading term. My guess is that this will turn out to be second derivative term. That is because if $u(x)$ goes as $(1-x)^2$, the second derivative is a constant. Substitute this back into your equation, and see what happens.

Comment: That looks a promising way to do it. The book says that the solution is $(1-x)^{1/2 \left [ 1 - \sqrt{1- \frac{4q}{cs}} \right ]}$ So I think the reasoning must be in that way. I'm going to try next a $(1-x)^m$ ($m$ real) based in that argument and I'll try to show that $m=1/2 \left [ 1 - \sqrt{1- \frac{4q}{cs}} \right ] $. I think it's legit.